# why I cant append a row in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, listiterator

I have 2 dim list, which contains duplicated elements in some lists as shown below

```
  myData=[['a',1,10],['b',2,20],['a',3,30],['a',4,40]]
```

I want to do:

- create 2 empty lists called(duplicatedLists, uniqueLists)
- read the first column/(element) in each list of myData
- if the first column/element does not exist in uniqueLists, then append the 
  entire row to uniqueLists
- if it exists in uniqueLists, then append the entire row to duplicatedList(do 
  not append to uniqueList)

I wrote the code below:

```
duplicatedLists=[]

uniqueLists=[]

myData=[['a',1,10],['b',2,20],['a',3,30],['a',4,40]]

for row in myData:

    print(row[0])


    if(row[0] not in uniqueLists):

        uniqueLists.append(row)

    else:

        duplicatedLists.append(row)

print(uniqueLists)

print(duplicatedLists)


so my result should be:

    uniqueLists=[['a',1,10],['b',2,20]]

    duplicatedLists=[[['a',3,30],['a',4,40]].
```

however I get this result:

```
[['a', 1, 10], ['b', 2, 20], ['a', 3, 30], ['a', 4, 40]]



[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in this line `if(row[0] not in uniqueLists):` You are checking for first element but you are appending the entire sub-list in to `uniqueLists` list

Instead Try:

```
myData=[['a',1,10],['b',2,20],['a',3,30],['a',4,40]]
duplicatedLists=[]
uniqueLists=[]
check_val = set()
for i in myData:
    if i[0] not in check_val:     #Check if value in set. 
        uniqueLists.append(i)
        check_val.add(i[0])       #! Add only first element to perform check. 
    else:
        duplicatedLists.append(i)

print(uniqueLists)       #[['a', 1, 10], ['b', 2, 20]]
print(duplicatedLists)   #[['a', 3, 30], ['a', 4, 40]]
```

Comment: I didn't get your point what is the mistake exactly, however, I liked your way of solving this issue. thank you very much for your help, I really appreciated it

Comment: Your comparison look like this `"a"` not in `[['a',1,10],['b',2,20],['a',3,30],['a',4,40]]`